# How to turn off file permissions boxes on Catalina for external drive?

Tags: macos, external-disk, permission, catalina

I use a trash-can Mac Pro. All my user files are on an external drive. Catalina constantly asks me if program X should be allowed to access a removable drive.

Is there any way to give all programs access to the drive at once and stop the permission dialog boxes?

Comment: You want to end this for all programs or just program X ?

Comment: All programs. Everything on my system is on an external drive, it's asking me this for every single thing on my machine.